# Run Selenium without wrapper installed

Tags: excel, selenium, late-binding, vba

I am creating a tool in Excel for making Google chrome themes. Ultimately, I'd like to install a .crx file on someone's machine automatically, but this requires uploading files to chrome://extensions to be compiled, then installing the compiled file.

I'm a long way off yet, but in the intrest of planning I've found out about Selenium which may help me in the necessary Chrome manipulations to install the theme.
My question is: Can Selenium be late bound and made to run on a computer without it installed? For most objects, late binding is:

```
Dim objIE As Object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

But I don't see how I can do that without Selenium installed - as `CreateObject` won't know where to look for the reference. Can I specify some online service so that my users don't have to download the Selenium wrapper to use my macros?

Comment: This may be what you're looking for: https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/

Comment: @BillHileman Actually that site specifically mentions 'Selenium VBA wrapper library' as a prerequisite! I would like to run macros without that installed

Comment: I don't see a way around it.  VBA cannot create an object without the corresponding object already installed.  Sure, you can create an object of office from within excel, for example, but that's only because it is (obviously) already installed, as are the other components of office.  But it cannot create an object of something that's not already been installed and configured.  Selenium was meant for browser control specifically for testing - it was never meant to be an end-user product, as far as I know.  Wish I had a better answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a Unix Script from Excel Vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796017/call-a-unix-script-from-excel-vba)

Comment: @PaulSweatte not a duplicate I don't think, I certainly wouldn't be able to answer this question based purely on that answer. But I think I get the idea, only - what should I replace this line with `Set console = shell.Exec("c:\putty\plink -telnet telehack.com -P 443")` in (Comintern's answer)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/41416923/6609896]? I'm not quite there with the terminology but I guess I just switch this line for something to do with the Selenium "server" (whatever that really means), and send commands in a similar way?

Comment: @Greedo I agree. In terms of next steps, setting up Selenium on a remote server, then manually connecting to it using putty and saving the connection profile would be the thing to do. To automate the process, use a command like `plink.exe -load seleniumserverputtyprofile -batch -l username -pw password java -jar selenium-server.jar`. The [plink man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/plink) and the [putty man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/putty) should help for future reference.