# Execute .bat file then input IP Address, to open PuTTY session that will then have further commands

Tags: excel, vba

Issue: We have a list of over 1000 intersections that routinely need firmware upgrades. The excel sheet have the device ID, intersection name and IP address.

Goal: We would like to use our excel directory to ping these intersection devices (controllers) and then run the firmware upgrade. The batch file runs a program that requires us to input the IP address for the intersection in question and then it opens a PuTTY session that has a number of menus that guide you through upgrading the firmware (these are commands like "1","5", etc)

I have tried this for a day, and I have gotten to the point of being able to open the batch file if I get a positive result from ping.

Current Code:

```
Sub FirmwareUpgradeStatus()

'setting values of variables
Set Wks = Worksheets("Upgrade")

Set ipRng = Wks.Range("F2")
Set RngEnd = Wks.Cells(Rows.Count, ipRng.Column).End(xlUp)
Set ipRng = IIf(RngEnd.Row < ipRng.Row, ipRng, Wks.Range(ipRng, RngEnd))

Dim FirmwareUpgrade As Object
Set FirmwareUpgrade = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

'this is a loop that feeds each server from the list into the GetPingResult 
function

For Each Cell In ipRng
Result = GetPingResult(Cell)
    If Result = "Connected" Then
    ChDir "C:\Users\C000XXXX\Desktop\maxtime_1.9.11"
    FirmwareUpgrade.Run "C:\Users\C000XXXX\Desktop\maxtime_1.9.11\install.cmd /c ""Cell""", windowStyle, waitOnReturn
    'Shell "C:\Users\C000XXXX\Desktop\maxtime_1.9.11\install.cmd" & "&&Cell"
    End If
  Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: This is good progress! I'm not sure what the next step is though. Are you wanting this script to input the ip address at this point? Since we don't have any control over how your batch file runs (I assume) then I think `Application.SendKeys()` to actually mimic keyboard strokes/typing is probably your best bet. Unless the batch file can take in parameters, then those could be passed in your `.Run` command.

Comment: If you need to open a shell in interactive mode, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41416923/4088852) demonstrates how to do that.