# keep Shell / cmd open when launching R script from VBA

Tags: r, excel, vba

I have an R script that is being run from an Excel workbook via a button that is linked to a VBA script.

The problem is every time the R script encounters an error - say it does not find one of the files it was supposed to read - the Shell / cmd window the R script is running in closes down instantly. The problem with that is you cannot see any clues as to why it failed. I then have to debug it manually by modifying the code and running in RStudio to find the errors - usually I have to do this for other people that do not know R.

The VBA code I use was copied and modified from one of the SO posts I found here. I am not very proficient in VBA and do not understand a lot of the code so I'm looking for a simple solution to this. My VBA code is this:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub RunRscript()

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
    Dim style As Integer: style = 1

    Dim scriptPath As String
    scriptPath = Range("F5").Value

    Dim argument As String
    argument = Range("F3").Value

    Dim path As String
    path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\Rscript.exe"" """ & scriptPath & """ """ 
& argument & """"

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Dim errorcode As Integer
    errorcode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

`scriptPath` points to the path of the R script and `argument` is an argument I pass to the R script.

I have tried passing the usual arguments to keep the cmd window open but I didn't manage to figure it out. This is also complicated by the fact that as mentioned I do not understand VBA syntax very well and the 'path' variable being very convoluted because of those endless double quotes.

Comment: If you just need to capture the output of the shelled command, you can use `Exec` instead of `Run` - that gives you access to the console output.

Comment: It's additionally confusing that you pass `var2` to your `R` script as the first parameter then `var1` as the script's second parameter. You may want to consider renaming those variables which reflect the data they're holding (perhaps `scriptPath` and `argument`) or at least put them in the numerical order they'll be used. Future programmers who have to maintain this code (including future you) will thank you.

Comment: @Comintern thanks for the suggestion - however replacing Run with Exec returns the error `Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`
Just to be clear - with Run - the cmd does pops up and you can see what it's doing as long as it's running. The problem is it closes down once it encounters an error or finishes the R script - and I would like to keep it open

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks for the advice. Absolutely fair, I agree. I did it in a rush and never got to modify it.
Any clues as to how I can solve the problem I mentioned? Thanks

Comment: Can you pipe the outcome of your R script to another file? Then you'd have the fun and privilege of parsing the output file (either manually or automatically) and it wouldn't matter if the shell closes on script exit.

Comment: made changes to code as suggested by @FreeMan to improve readability

Comment: psst... now you have uncompilable code. :)  `scriptPath` & `argument` aren't declared and you have `Option Explicit` set (as you should!). Also, `var1` and `var2` are now declared without being used. Sorry for the code review, I know that's not what you're after...

Comment: @FreeMan, the output of the R script is actually a series of Excel workbooks that it opens, prints data in and then saves.
it reads a list with the paths of all the files it needs to read as an input to generate the output data required to print in excel.
Sometimes, one of the paths in that list is wrong, so the program stops halfway and there is no clue as to why for the user. (the reason could be something else as well).
It would be good if I could pass the text that is generated in shell / cmd automatically to a notepad / textpad file at least, so the user could then open and check.

Comment: @FreeMan haha, no worries. I've corrected it now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use

```
errorcode = shell.Run("cmd /k " & path, style, waitTillComplete)
```

instead of

```
errorcode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
```

We open a new instance of the command-line tool, thus can use its parameters. The parameter /k **k**eeps the cmd-window open (use /c to **c**lose). After the cmd-parameter we add the script to be executed.

**But** there is one problem: if you close the cmd-window, VBA throws an overflow error. I use a flag in my Excel sheet to switch between debug mode and normal mode:

```
debugging = Range("N5").Value 'True/False
If debugging Then
    errorCode = shell.Run("cmd /k " & path, style, waitTillComplete)
Else
    errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
End If
```

If the script fails I rerun it setting debug mode to True in a cell of the Excel sheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot - much appreciated,
However I now get the <C:\Program is not recognized as internal or external program...>. 
The quotes now probably need re-adjusting - I've had this before when defining the <path> variable and I spent like a day trying to figure out how the quotes need to be placed.
Let me know if you know hot to fix this.

Comment: Hm...IMO Shell.Run should take strings as they are. I only do this:
path = "RScript Z:\[...]\report.R" and do not unterstand the """"""-mess you have to use in your script.

Comment: I'm not at work right now, thus cannot test. What happens if you type ```path = "cmd /k Rscript " & scriptPath & " " & argument``` or ```path = "cmd /k C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\Rscript.exe " & scriptPath & " " & argument```?

Comment: None of this works unfortunately. I've spent hours trying to make it work.

The reason I need all those quotes is because of spaces in the paths of the Rscript and the actual .R file containing the code.

I've added the Rscript parent folder to my environment variables and it does seem to work from cmd if I type Rscript.exe, but not from the cmd launched by VBA Shell.

Comment: This is a older now but I had the same problem but managed to fixed it.
I am running python from VBA and found that the problem was related to the use of " in the path. 
originally I just added `cmd /k` to the start of the existing path which resulted in:
`cmd /k "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe"` however this did not work. 
combining `cmd /k` with the path so that there were no "'s between the `cmd /k` and the path worked. The updated path looks like this:
`cmd /k C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment:

> @FreeMan, the output of the R script is actually a series of Excel workbooks that it opens, prints data in and then saves. it reads a list with the paths of all the files it needs to read as an input to generate the output data required to print in excel. Sometimes, one of the paths in that list is wrong, so the program stops halfway and there is no clue as to why for the user. (the reason could be something else as well). It would be good if I could pass the text that is generated in shell / cmd automatically to a notepad / textpad file at least, so the user could then open and check

It sounds like the best bet may be to have your `R` script validate the paths/files prior to attempting to do its processing. I'm barely familiar with `R`, but what I know of it there should be a library *somewhere* that will allow you to test for the existence of a path and/or a file on that path. If it doesn't exist, the script would simply put an error message in the file it was *supposed* to create/update indicating that it couldn't find the requested path/file, or it could write that message to an error log that could be opened by your VBA code at the completion of its processing.

Comment: That is an idea, but it's not exactly the kind of solution I would ideally want.
Should I understand that it is impossible to keep the Shell window open when run from VBA?

Comment: You've had Comintern and Mathieu Guindon looking at your question - they know _far_ more about the terrifying depths of VBA than I do. If they haven't provided you with an answer, I wouldn't say it _can't_ be done, but it certainly ain't gonna be easy.

Comment: @Livius - Comintern just pointed my to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41416923/4088852) he wrote on a similar question that should get you headed in the correct direction. I can take no credit for it beyond simply passing the message along.