# vba excel macro to use adb

Tags: excel, vba, adb, ctrl

i'm trying to create a macro that allows me to take screenshot, video and retrieve them via adb.
using shell + line i can do almost everything, but i cannot stop recording.
the stop recording command is ctrl+c, but sending it via sendkeys is not working.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    If ComboBox1.Value = "data, ora e titolo" Then
        nomevideo = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy_hh-mm-ss_") & "_" & TextBox2.Value & ".mp4"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "data e titolo" Then
        nomevideo = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy_") & TextBox2.Value & ".mp4"
    Else
        nomevideo = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy_hh-mm-ss") & ".mp4"
    End If
    video = "adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/" & nomevideo
    Debug.Print video & "registra video"
    Shell video
    CommandButton13.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    SendKeys "^c"
    Debug.Print "stop video"
End Sub
```

Comment: what this question ha in common with the C language. Why do you spam tags

Comment: my tag was ctrl+c, sorry!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to activate the window of adb using AppActivate prior to sending control-c. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/appactivate-statement for details.

Ok, keep the window open when using shell: [keep Shell / cmd open when launching R script from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536935/keep-shell-cmd-open-when-launching-r-script-from-vba)

Comment: I tried activating dos prompt, and it didn't work. also tried manually stopping it from prompt with ctrl+c, but it's not the same window where -shell "adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/test.mp4" starts recording, and it didn't work

Comment: How did you activate the DOS prompt? Manually?

Comment: i didn't activate it, shell sent commands directly to prompt, without showing window

Comment: Ok, when the adb process is launched, does any window appear? How do you normally stop it?

Comment: sorry, i now understand what i was doing... I use adb via prompt, but writing "shell "adb etc. i'm talking directly with adb. so I need to activate adb and use sendkeys. can you tell me how to activate the window? appactivate and ?

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
Dim programma As Long, newhour, newminute, newsecond, waittime As Variant
   programma = Shell("C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", vbNormalFocus)
AppActivate programma
   newhour = Hour(Now())
   newminute = Minute(Now())
   newsecond = Second(Now()) + 1
   waittime = TimeSerial(newhour, newminute, newsecond)
Application.Wait waittime
Application.SendKeys ("adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/gigio.mp4~"), True
AppActivate programma
   newhour = Hour(Now())
   newminute = Minute(Now())
   newsecond = Second(Now()) + 1
   waittime = TimeSerial(newhour, newminute, newsecond)
Application.Wait waittime
Application.SendKeys ("^c"), True
```