# Automate FTP upload with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, ftp

I am trying to automate the following process:

1. Data imported to Microsoft Excel (`myfile.xls`) from database and formatted.
2. File saved as `myfile.txt`.
3. Uploaded via `FTP` to a server.

I have got as far as the `FTP` upload, but I am having issues with the batch file created within the `VBA` script.

The current script I have is as follows:

```
Dim MY_FILENAME As String
MY_FILENAME = "C:\user\sam\test" & "filename" & Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm") & ".BAT"


Dim FileNumber As Integer
Dim retVal As Variant

FileNumber = FreeFile

'create batch file
Open MY_FILENAME For Output As #FileNumber
Print #FileNumber, "FTP 00.0.000.000"
Print #FileNumber, "username"
Print #FileNumber, "password"
Print #FileNumber, "ascii crlf"
Print #FileNumber, "put  " myfile.txt; "  'location'"
Print #FileNumber, "exit"
Close #FileNumber

'run batch file
retVal = Shell(MY_FILENAME, vbNormalFocus)
```

When I run this script, it opens the IP associated to the server, but fails to enter the login credentials. Can anyone advise where I am going wrong?

Comment: I cannot see any Windows [tag:batch-file] in your post, so I removed the related tags; please read the tag info before assigning them...

Comment: Hi aschipfl, the script above creates a batch file and then runs it. the content of the batch file is: FTP 00.0.000.000,
username,
password,
ascii crlf,
put   myfile.txt;  'location',
exit

Comment: @aschipfl it is *obvious* that this post is about creating a batch file !!!

Comment: @samc it would help if you'd add the declaration of `MY_FILENAME` to the snippet above.

Comment: @steenbergh MY_FILENAME only refers to the batch file being created and its location, but sure i will add it for clarity.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez, actually it is not, it is about creation of a script for `ftp.exe`, which the OP erroneously mixes up with a Windows [tag:batch-file], which cannot work; instead of trying to call a batch-file that runs `ftp.exe`, the VBA script should directly run `ftp.exe` and pass the created script to it by its `-s` option; nevertheless I re-added the tag batch-file and added the [tag:ftp] tag...

Comment: If you don't need to persist the script, you should be able to just use `WScript.Shell` in interactive mode instead. You'll find a sample using putty [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41416923/4088852) that should be adaptable to using ftp instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's going wrong is that the batch file first opens `ftp` in interactive mode and receives no input. If `ftp` woud terminate on its own, you'd notice that your batch file then goes on to execute the instructions `username`, `password` etc. Those aren't meant as instructions to Batch but to `ftp`, but that's not how Batch would see it.

To work around that, save all the `ftp` instructions to a second file, then call `ftp` in Batch with the second file as input parameter:

```
Dim FileNumber As Integer
Dim retVal As Variant
FileNumber = FreeFile

'create batch file
Open MY_FILENAME For Output As #FileNumber
Print #FileNumber, "FTP -s<your-filename-here> 00.0.000.000"
Close #FileNumber

Open FTP_INSTRUCTIONS For Output As #FileNumber
Print #FileNumber, "username"
Print #FileNumber, "password"
Print #FileNumber, "ascii crlf"
Print #FileNumber, "put  " myfile.txt; "  'location'"
Print #FileNumber, "exit"
Close #FileNumber

'run batch file
retVal = Shell(MY_FILENAME, vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: thank you for a clear explanation of my issue. Just to confirm there is no way that you know of to have it run from 1 file?

Comment: @samc no, I don't think there is. All you're trying to do doesn't fit in the cmd line paameters of `ftp`, so you need to use the second file. Depending on your environment, you might just be able to create 1 instrcutinsfile, then call `Shell('ftp -s:<filename>')` instead of the Batch file.

Comment: You don't need a batch file. All you should need is an ftp script file and have the VBA directly run ftp.exe with the script file as a parameter.

Comment: @Squashman you are correct, i found the syntax to open FTP without using a batch file: Shell Environ("WINDIR") & "\System32\ftp.exe -n -s:" & <File with instruction>