# Sendkeys in VBS not working properly in telnet session

Tags: vbscript, telnet

I am trying to right a VBS Code in which a telnet session opens and does the command and then saves the output in the telnet session. 
My issue is when i run the .vbs file it runs and simultaneously when i open a notepad the sendkeys function sends the keys to the notepad instead of running it in telnet session. I want the commands only to be running in Telnet session, no matter whatever program runs simultaneously.

Here is my vbs code:

```
Option Explicit    
On Error Resume Next
Dim oShell
set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "telnet.exe -f data.csv"
WScript.Sleep 3000
oShell.Sendkeys "o 10.1.1.142~"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.Sendkeys "E{%}.~"
WScript.Sleep 3000
oShell.Sendkeys ".{%}c13,0;0.3.1{%}y"
WScript.Sleep 100000
oShell.Sendkeys "^]"
oShell.Sendkeys "quit~"
```

Please help. I tried the AppActivate thing. but didn't worked. I just want my commands to run in telnet not in any other program opened at the moment.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Open your shell in interactive mode and just write to standard input.  [There's an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41416923/4088852).

Comment: @Comintern Tried. Not working. Can you try , if it works for you !

Comment: What is "not working"? Replace the `run` call with `exec`, and then replace the `Sendkeys` commands with `StdIn.Write`. That should be all there is to it.

Comment: @Comintern I tried it. but it flashes up and goes. nothing is working. Here is the code


    Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Dim oShell 'As Object
set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Exec("telnet.exe -f data.csv")
WScript.Sleep 3000
oShell.StdIn.Write("o 10.1.1.142~")
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.StdIn.Write("E{%}.~")
WScript.Sleep 3000
oShell.StdIn.Write(".{%}c13,0;0.3.1{%}y")
WScript.Sleep 100000
oShell.StdIn.Write("^]")
oShell.StdIn.Write("quit~")

Comment: Does it work from the command line?  On my machine, `telnet.exe` isn't in the PATH, so it would error on the `Exec` line.  Take the `On Error Resume Next` out and see if you get an error.

Comment: @Comintern it works on the command line. But the same question. all the commands are getting entered into a notepad if it is open. not in the telnet session

Comment: That's because `Sendkeys` is literally like typing on the keyboard.  Did you remove `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: @Comintern Tried removing the on error resume next. throws an error. at line oShell.StdIn.Write() saying  object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: I didn't read the source in the comment closely enough (it's a bit hard to read there).  You need to capture the returned `WshScriptExec` from `oShell.Exec` in another object variable - `oShell` isn't going to have the IO streams - the `WshScriptExec` object does.  The [documentation is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/ateytk4a(v=vs.84)).

Comment: @Comintern does nothing

Comment: As always, DO NOT use `SendKeys` in an attempt to try to automate the buitin `telenet` command. Use a `telnet` command that is actually scriptable, like [`plink`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) from the [PuTTY suite](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).